# Setting color of Circle Patch in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

Setting the color or a Circle patch directly is not supported through class methods as we might assume;

```
circle.set_color('b')
```

^^ this is incorrect.

Comment: Because you need to set the `facecolor` or `edgecolor`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Patches have two distinct colors, `facecolor` and `edgecolor`, which you can set by, respectively `c.set_facecolor(...)` (or `set_fc`) and `c.set_edgecolor(...)`(or `set_ec`).

The `setp` machinery is just a convince method for looking up these functions. `setp(artist, key=val)` does, more-or-less  `getattr(artist, "set_%s" % key)(val)`.

Comment: Would you happen to have additional information for this problem..... http://stackoverflow.com/q/23915859/1602222