# How to efficiently alter the color in an animation of patches circles in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a visualization for a networking routing simulation, where the network is represented by 2D circle patches in matplotlib.

I am using Matplotlib's animation to show the simulated routing.

Looking into Matplotlib.collections , it appears there isn't a nice way to random access circle objects in order to quickly alter their color and redraw the collection.

Any suggestions on how to continue would be greatly appreciated!

Currently, my animation is as follows:

```
def init():
  pass


def animate(i):
  global network_nodes, active_stack, nums
  import matplotlib.artist as mplart

  #hard coded routes
  n = routes(i)
  network_nodes = {}

  # draw colorless network
  network_gen(levels,0.0,radius,0.0,0.0)    


 # simplified alterations
 network_nodes[n].set_facecolor('blue')


 # add the patch
 fig.gca().add_patch(network_nodes[c][0])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the color of objects in a [patch collection](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/collections_api.html) by setting the collection's color map and then changing the image array with [set_array](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.set_array) at each step of the animation. In the example below the image array is random as inspired by [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/patch_collection.html).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

patches = []
# create circles with random sizes and locations
N = 10 # number of circles
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
radii  = 0.1*np.random.rand(N)
for x1,y1,r in zip(x, y, radii):
    circle = Circle((x1,y1), r)
    patches.append(circle)

# add these circles to a collection
p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=cm.prism, alpha=0.4)
ax.add_collection(p)

def animate(i):
    colors = 100*np.random.rand(len(patches)) # random index to color map
    p.set_array(np.array(colors)) # set new color colors
    return p,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=50, interval=50)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice explanation ! Thank you